# ORACLE ¿Como puedo actualizar una fila cuando se cumpla una condición?

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito algún tipo de procedimiento o trigger o si es que existe algún otro método que verifique: si una fecha de una row es igual a SYSDATE se actualiza una row

explico un poco el contexto:

**Tabla: Reserva**

- ID
- FechaEmision
- FechaInicio
- FechaFin
- Habitacion_IdHabitacion(FK)

**Tabla: Habitacion**:

- ID
- ESTADO

**Lo que necesito es algo como:**

```
if (fechaInicio == SYSDATE){
 update Habitacion set estado='ocupado' where id = Habitacion_IdHabitacion;
}
if (fechaFin == SYSDATE){
 update Habitacion set estado='disponible' where id = Habitacion_IdHabitacion;
}
```

que se este ejecutando o loopeando cada dia u hora

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar jobs o tareas planificadas? Es muy posible que te sirva: http://www.orasite.com/administracion-de-oracle/oracle-jobs-planificando-tareas-en-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres deberías crear un job que se lance cuando tú lo configures, por ejemplo todos los días a las 00:00 y haga el update de la tabla con la condición que quieras.